# Grails 4 - why is domain class not being marked as dirty?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The complaint: Grails 4.0.10, Gorm 7.0.8.RELEASE does not set the domain class isDirty flag in all cases, and therefore no update is performed to the backend.

In Grails 3 I have for years had working code in a filter that handles token logins.  Upon success this code is executed:

```
User.withTransaction {
    User user = User.get(userDetails.id)
    Date now = new Date();
    user.loginSuccess(now, userDetails.ipAddr, idno, true)
}
```

The User.loginSucess() method is this:

```
void loginSuccess(Date when, String ipAddr, String idno = null, boolean flush = false) {
    lastLoginDate = loginDate
    loginDate = when.toTimestamp()
    lastUpdated = when.toTimestamp()
    lastLoginIp = loginIp
    loginIp = ipAddr
    loginFailedCount = 0
    firstFailedDate = null
    idno = idno
    save(flush: flush, validate: false)
}
```

This code never updates the database, regardless of the state of the flush flag, unless I trigger isDirty somehow.  I do it by changing

```
lastUpdated = when.toTimestamp()
```

to

```
this.setLastUpdated(when.toTimestamp())
```

This peculiar nature of setting the dirty flag existed years ago in Grails 2.  Is this different behavior expected and an oversight on my part?  (The User.lastUpdated property is nothing special - a Date field mapped as sqlType: 'Timestamp' for writing to Postgres.)

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1097.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like my code has been out-of-date all this time, working correctly only due to some fluke.

Comment: "Is this different behavior expected and an oversight on my part? " - I think so.

Comment: GORM by default will initialize and update your `lastUpdated` for you, and the mechanism that GORM uses to do that is compatible with the underlying Hibernate dirty checking.  What are the use cases where you want to update `lastUpdated` yourself?

Comment: I am aware of the autotimestamp feature, and our domain classes use it in affiliation with a trait that adds some other audit data.  I will need to go back and review the reasoning, but the User class handles lastUpdated explicitly.  I think it is was related to some login handling that may no longer be relevant.  That said, I have switched to setters in the code above so the dirty value is appropriately set regardless of which property may have changed.

Comment: I am a little surprised your manual assignment approach is working and not being overridden with the autotimestamp one, but I am glad you got it working.  Well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking JSB's comment as the explanation of the behavior, and the answer.